# Link perl xsub via Perl packager

Tags: perl, linker-errors, pp-perl-par-packager

I have created one perl xsub to call a C function from my perl script.But the problem is that I cannot install that xsub directly by "make install'.The xsub has been created by make command already in the mentioned folder.I have to use it without installing it.Also I am using Perl packager to create executable for my perl script.here is my make file-

```
    PP=/usr/local/bin/pp
    INSTALL=/usr/bin/install
    PROG=nsgslbautosync
    SDIR=../scripts
    SRCS=$(SDIR)/syncgslbconfig.pl

    nsgslbautosync:$(SRCS) 
       $(PP) --lib GslbSync/lib/GslbSync.pm --link GslbSync/blib/arch/auto/GslbSync/GslbSync.so -o $@ $<
```

Now the problem is that even after linking the xsub,I am getting the following error on running the script-

```
    Can't locate GslbSync.pm in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x802941930)/var/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-dbeb96ca0c7f9489e2bfc7a2fc11650939727dbd/inc/lib /var/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-dbeb96ca0c7f9489e2bfc7a2fc11650939727dbd/inc CODE(0x80226dde0)CODE(0x802276060)) at script/syncgslbconfig.pl line 20.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/syncgslbconfig.pl line .ERROR:
```

I even tried to link the xsub in my script by using "use lib" but no luck, got the same error.